# Override GWT Date serialization override

Tags: java, date, serialization, gwt, timezone

I'm having trouble with GWT's default local timezone conversion behavior. I need to pass dates between the client and server all in UTC, and I want no conversion to take place.

I've read a few stack questions ([here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799884/is-there-other-solution-than-hack-date-customfieldserializer-and-recompile-gwt)) that say the answer is to override GWT's serialization of java.util.Date. It seems easy because it just needs to do the same thing as GWT's Date but skip the conversion. But I don't know how to even do that.

Has anyone successfully done this and can they provide an example? I've created a client and server Date_CustomFieldSerializer ([described here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideCustomSerialization)) but I'm not sure how to implement it any differently than GWT's implementation of basically using Date's getTime() and setTime(long).

Comment: You can simply pass dates as milliseconds or Strings - both options remove any time zone issues.

Comment: Yea I was trying to avoid that. I realized that my Date object's getTime() values weren't being changed, so I could grab the miliseconds from that. Actually it was just GWT's formatting that was causing my problems. I ended copying the DateTimeFormat GWT source code and manipulated it slightly to not check the client's TZ. I pointed my code to that instead of DateTimeFormat and everything is working fine now.